# Print statement issue using .format

Tags: python, string.format

My code looks like:

```
import scipy.stats as st

DISTRIBUTIONS = [ st.burr,st.cauchy,st.chi,st.chi2,st.cosine,st.dgamma]

    for distribution in DISTRIBUTIONS:
       params = distribution.fit(df['diff']) #df['diff'] is the data frame column
       print ' Generating params for distribution {0}:'.format(distribution)
       ##Do something further
```

In the output  of print statement I do not get the distribution name. Rather I get the scipy object name as:

```
Generating params for distribution <scipy.stats._continuous_distns.burr_gen object at 0x7f16d8b9a050>
```

Comment: are you really doing `print ' Generating params for distribution {0}:'.format('distribution')` ? do you really have the ' quotes around distribution?

Comment: Presumably your actual code doesn't have `distribution` as a literal string? :p That would be returning `Generating params for distribution distribution`...

Comment: Yeah it was a typo...no quotes are there..have edited the question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `scipy.stat` objects have a `name` attribute, print that instead:

```
import scipy.stats as st

DISTRIBUTIONS = [ st.burr,st.cauchy,st.chi,st.chi2,st.cosine,st.dgamma]

for distribution in DISTRIBUTIONS:
   params = distribution.fit(df['diff']) #df['diff'] is the data frame column
   print ' Generating params for distribution {0.name}:'.format(distribution)
       ##Do something further
```

Example:

```
>>> for distro in DISTRIBUTIONS: 
...     print('{0.name}'.format(distro))
... 
burr
cauchy
chi
chi2
cosine
dgamma
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
import scipy.stats as st

DISTRIBUTIONS = {"burr": st.burr, "cauchy":st.cauchy,"chi":st.chi,"chi2":st.chi2,"cosine":st.cosine,"dgamma":st.dgamma}

for distribution in DISTRIBUTIONS:
   params = DISTRIBUTIONS[distribution].fit(df['diff']) #df['diff'] is the data frame column
   print ' Generating params for distribution {0}:'.format(distribution)
   ##Do something further
```

That will print the key which has the string you're looking for I think?

EDIT: the other answer is better. I didn't know about .name. :)